# please advice simple javascript file upload for using in ASP.NET mvc project

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I need to implement async file upload in my ASP.NET mvc project.
It should use **javascript only** (flash and silverlight denied) and support IE7-9. I already try valums file uploader, but it do not support IE9. Please advice, need to implement this functionality urgently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [AjaxFileUpload](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/) good enough for my needs

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using iframes and regular input[type=file] in a form ,you cant.